# Can't Read RTF ANSi File contains Arabic Characters

Tags: java, character-encoding, java-8, rtf

I have `RTF` files are encoded in `ANSI` while it contains `Arabic` phrases. I'm trying to read this file but couldn't read it in the right encoding.

RTF File:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset178 MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}

\viewkind4\uc1\pard\ltrpar\lang12289\f0\rtlch\fs16\'ca\'d1\'cc\'e3\'c9: \'d3\'e3\'ed\'d1 \'c7\'e1\'e3\'cc\'d0\'e6\'c8\f1\ltrch\par

}
```

and my java code is:

```
RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
Document doc = rtf.createDefaultDocument();
rtf.read(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Document.rtf"), "windows-1256"),doc,0);
System.out.println(doc.getText(0,doc.getLength()));
```

and the wrong output is:

```
ÊÑÌãÉ: ÓãíÑ ÇáãÌÐæÈ
```

Comment: As far as I can see, Swing is not supporting, and silently ignoring, the `\fcharset178` instruction of your RTF file and there’s nothing you can do about it as all relevant classes involved in that process are non-`public`…

Comment: so is there any way to replace some characters in `RTF` file to read it correctly ? or in general there is o JAVA library to read Arabic chars from `RTF` files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [RTFParserKit](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit), this should correctly support encodings like the ones you describe.

Here is the text it extracted from your example:

> ترجمة: سمير المجذوب

I used the `RtfDump` class which ships with RTFParserKit to dump the RTF content into an XML file. The class invokes the `StandardRtfParser` on the supplied input file, while the `RtfDumpListener` class receives the events raised by the parser as the file is read, adding content to the XML file as it goes.

Comment: That's the correct text , can you write the code ? couldn't find any example for `RTFParseKit` usage .

Comment: I've add a brief note about the `RtfDump` example code.

Comment: Thx a lot Jon .. very useful answer